# Angular Ionic parameter passed by state

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I receive a parameter passed by state in the URL on another page?
I have this code to send the parameter to the next page.

```
let costcountry = this.requestAmountData.costCenterCountryId    
this.router.navegateByUrl(`exampleurl`, {state: { costcountry: costcountry}});
```

But I don't know how to receive it to use it on the next page. any ideas?
TK

Comment: Check this thread on ionic form: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-from-1-page-to-another-using-navigation-in-ionic-4/151060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Approach with `ActivatedRoute`:

Page 1:

```
gotoYourPage(paramsToSend){
     this.router.navigate(['/YourPageName', { yourDataKey : JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)}]);
}
```

Page2:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private aroute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

this.receiveData = JSON.parse(this.aroute.snapshot.params.yourDataKey );
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Method - Router Navigation:**

// First Page:

> constructor(private router: Router){
>
> }
>
> functionname() {
>
> this.router.navigateByUrl('/secondpage', { state: { id: id_data, name:
> txt_name} }) }

// Second Page:

> listdata: any;
>
> id: any;
>
> name: any;
>
> constructor(private router: Router){
>
> this.listdata = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
>
> this.id = this.listdata['id'];
>
> this.name = this.listdata['name'];
>
> }

**Second Method - HTML RouterLink:**

First Page:

> <ion-button routerLink="/secondpage" [state]="{id: id_data, name: 'myname'}">

Second Page:

> listdata: any;
>
> id: any;
>
> name: any;
>
> constructor(private router: Router){
>
> this.listdata = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
>
> this.id = this.listdata['id'];
>
> this.name = this.listdata['name']; }